# Dynamically Change Option Set Values in CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using CRM Online 2013.

I am trying to remove 3 values from an optionset under a certain condition.
The optionset has six options by default: they are listed at the top of my JS code below.

When I run my code, the correct amount of options appear; but they all say undefined.

[image: Undefined Image example]

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
var customer = 100000000;
var partner = 100000001;
var partnerCustomer = 100000002;
var customerAndBeta = 100000003;
var partnerAndBeta = 100000004;
var partnerCustomerAndBeta = 100000005;

function populateBetaOptionSet(beta) {
    var options = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("intip_websiteaccess").getOptions();
    var pickListField = Xrm.Page.getControl("intip_websiteaccess");

    for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
        pickListField.removeOption(options[i].value);           
    }

    if (beta == false) {
        pickListField.addOption(customer);
        pickListField.addOption(partner);
        pickListField.addOption(partnerCustomer);
    }

    pickListField.addOption(customerAndBeta);
    pickListField.addOption(partnerAndBeta);
    pickListField.addOption(partnerCustomerAndBeta);
}
```

This is being called from another function which is wired up to a separate field's onchange event. I am sure this is working correctly as I am getting the correct beta value through when it is called.

I am removing all the options before re-adding them to avoid duplicates.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here/or know of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-wrote your function to match the criterion. The option is an object with both text and value. This is why you see undefined (missing text);
So instead of

```
var customer = 100000000
```

it needs to be

```
var customer = { value : 100000000 , text : "Customer" };
```

The code below saves each option in global scope and uses it each time you call populateBetaOptionSet

```
function populateBetaOptionSet(beta) {
    var xrmPage = Xrm.Page;
    var pickListField = xrmPage.getControl("intip_websiteaccess");
    var options = pickListField.getOptions();

    //save all options  
    if (!window.wsOptions)
    {
         window.wsOptions = {};
         wsOptions.customer = pickListField.getOption(100000000);
         wsOptions.partner = pickListField.getOption(100000001);
         wsOptions.partnerCustomer = pickListField.getOption(100000002);
         wsOptions.customerAndBeta = pickListField.getOption(100000003);
         wsOptions.partnerAndBeta = pickListField.getOption(100000004);
         wsOptions.partnerCustomerAndBeta = pickListField.getOption(100000005);
    }

    //clear all items
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
            pickListField.removeOption(options[i].value);           
    }

    if (beta == false) {
        pickListField.addOption(wsOptions.customer);
        pickListField.addOption(wsOptions.partner);
        pickListField.addOption(wsOptions.partnerCustomer);
    }

    pickListField.addOption(wsOptions.customerAndBeta);
    pickListField.addOption(wsOptions.partnerAndBeta);
    pickListField.addOption(wsOptions.partnerCustomerAndBeta);
}
```

Comment: Of course! This is a much cleaner approach to what I had. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Example use   Xrm.Page.getControl(..).addOption  :

```
    var low = {value : 100000000, text : "Low"};
    var medium = {value : 100000001, text : "Medium"};
    var high = {value : 100000002, text : "High"};

    var pickList = Xrm.Page.getControl("control_name");
    var options = pickList.getOptions();

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
        pickList.removeOption(options[i].value);

    pickList.addOption(low);
    pickList.addOption(medium);
    pickList.addOption(high);
```

Comment: Just a note that as of Nov 2018 (8.2.3.114), control.getOptions() returns null and the code "pickList.getOptions()" no longer works.