# How to associate two optionsets to one field in Dynamics CRM 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I have one field **field1**.
Now I want to set field value as per optionset selected.

Ex:
master field has 2 options,
if I select option1 from master field then **field1** should be filled with  Optionset1 
else 
 **field1** should be filled with  Optionset2

So is there any way to get it through crm without any code customization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No code solution is not possible yet for this cascading dropdown functionality in OOB Dynamics CRM.

[Dependent OptionSet Generator](http://crmoptionsets.azurewebsites.net) by Guido is your best bet.

[Minimal code & configuration by community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/webfortisblogunleashingyourcrm/archive/2015/01/27/another-approach-to-dependent-pick-lists)  and [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457643/7920473) are other choices.